# aosp can not boot for bullhead(lg nexus 5x)

Tags: android-source, fastboot

from branch

```
MDB08M  android-6.0.0_r26   Marshmallow Nexus 5X, Nexus 6P
```

I did

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_bullhead-userdebug
make -j16
```

then fastboot

```
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-bullhead-bhz10i.img       //this is from google's official rom.
fastboot flash radio radio-bullhead-m8994f-2.6.28.0.65.img     //this is from google's official rom.
fastboot reboot-bootloader  
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash boot boot.img                                   //build from aosp
fastboot flash vendor vendor.img                               //this is from google's official rom.
fastboot flash cache cache.img                                 //build from aosp
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img                           //build from aosp
fastboot flash system system.img                               //build from aosp
fastboot reboot
```

nothing, but stop at 'google' logo.

the official factory rom could be fastboot & boot succed.

Answer (score 0):

**You flashed the images in the wrong order.**
You need to flash system.img before you flash vendor and userdata.
Cache should be flashed last.

Here's the correct order:

```
$ fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img
$ fastboot flash radio radio.img

$ fastboot reboot-bootloader

$ fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
$ fastboot flash boot boot.img
$ fastboot flash system system.img

$ fastboot flash vendor vendor.img
$ fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
$ fastboot flash cache cache.img
$ fastboot oem lock
```

Now, if you did everything else correctly, it should boot.

Did you add the proprietary vendor images from LG and Qualcomm?
https://developers.google.com/android/drivers#bullhead